# Forms Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, custom-masterpage, list-form

I am loading lots of js and css in my master page. While I have no problem if a page loads a little slower, I need the forms to load faster, but they are based on the same master page.

I think it's stupid to load all the masterpage for a form and I don't know how to proceed.

Is there a way to base the forms on a different master page? Or block some unneeded scripts from loading?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it SharePoint online or on-premises? are you open for code base full trust solution?

Comment: It's Sharepoint Online and yes I am open to any suggestion, thank you.